How to write a line to a file at a given line index in C?
recently, I have a problem with indexing a line in a file in C.
For example I have the following poem written (By ChatGPT) in a text file:
In lands where ice once reigned supreme,
Now melts away, a silent scream.
Glaciers weep in rivers wide,
Their tears a warning, a rising tide.

Oceans swell with fevered heat,
As warming waters gently beat.
Their fading colors tell a tale.

Now I want to add this line Coral reefs, once vibrant, now pale, to the 6th index:
...
As warming waters gently beat.
                                 <-- here
Their fading colors tell a tale.

How do I do it easily with C? Is there a function to achieve this task?
Thanks.

There are a few problems with files, one of them is that it's not possible to "move" data. The simplest solution is to read the full current text file into memory, write it to a temporary file with the new added or modified text, and then rename the temporary file as the original file.

Maybe even simpler (somewhat similar to the solution in the previous comment): read the file line by line and write each line into a temporary file. Once you're at line number 6 (or whatever line), write the new line, then continue reading/writing until the end. At the end delete the original file and rename the temporary file.

@Someprogrammerdude agreeing here. If you're going minimal on library functions, you could try a 2D array, where each sub-array holds a single line, then create a function which inserts a new sub-array into your 2D array. Though that might not be the most efficient way to do things, if you're doing a lot of these insertions for example.

@Jabberwocky "At the end delete the original file and rename the temporary file." --> More error resistant to rename original file rather than delete, then rename the temporary file, then delete the renamed original file.  With good error checking, that reduces the chance than we lose data if something goes wrong. IOWs, do not delete the original data until after the new file is completely formed.

popen() an ed session and send it commands to edit the file.


How do I do it easily with C?

It takes a bit of code.

Is there a function to achieve this task?

No.

Use lots of error checking.

Read the original file "src" and copy it to a new file "tmp" up to the Nth line.

Append your new line to the new file.

Continue reading the original file "src" and append the rest of it to the new file "tmp".

Close new file "tmp".

Rename "src" to "src.bak"

Rename "tmp" to "src"

If all is successful, delete "src.bak" if desired.


